# Storing domain events with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, event-handling, domain-driven-design, cqrs, eventstoredb

I'm looking for a way to store events using Xamarin on a mobile device.

On the server there are event stores I can use, but I don't know what is possible with Xamarin mobile.

(e.g. https://geteventstore.com/)

Event store says it can run on mono, but I'm not sure if that means xamarin mobile.

I suppose I could use sqlite database to store events, but I'm new to all this and I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: An event store is usually used to store domain events. It's up to your domain layer, that should be on a server, to store them. The mobile device should not be responsible to store domain events. That being said, if you really need to do this, an event store is made of a really simple data structure that can be applied to almost everything (flat files, rdms, nosql, ...)

Comment: In my application people will take the app offline and still edit the information. Later syncing. It seems it would be very easy to sync by just sending the most recent domain events since last sync. Wouldn't just syncing the state of the object by counter productive to cqrs?